Trying to access session data via a queued job
I'm using queue to calculate the daily total of user transactions. A specific user can have transactions on different branches; I must change the session's branch to that user's branch in order to retrieve data from a table using the specific branch. The problem is that I am unable to access the session while running it as a queue. Is there a way to resolve this issue, or another way to access and change the session? The following is my job
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Services\newLedgerReport;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\Accounts\DailySummary;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

// To set session-like data in your job
Cache::put('branch', $branch);

// To retrieve session-like data in your job
$branch = Cache::get('branch');


class DailySummaryJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    protected $ledgerReport;

    public function __construct(newLedgerReport $ledgerReport)
    {
        $this->ledgerReport = $ledgerReport;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        set_time_limit(4680); // 90 minutes
        ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M'); // Increase memory limit
        try {
            $presentCompany = session('company');

            $branches = DB::table('branch_mgmt')->where('Company_ID', $presentCompany)->pluck('Branch_ID')->toArray();
            $fromDate = '2023-04-01';
            $toDate = now()->format('Y-m-d');

            DB::table('acc_ledger_master1')
                ->select('ledger_name', 'ledger_id', 'company_id', 'registering_branch', 'is_shared_among_all_branches')
                ->where('company_id', session('company'))
                ->where('registering_branch', '!=', 1)
                ->orderBy('ledger_id')
                ->chunk(100, function ($allUsers) use ($branches, $fromDate, $toDate) {
                    foreach ($allUsers as $currentLedger) {
                        $branchesToProcess = $currentLedger->is_shared_among_all_branches ? $branches : [$currentLedger->registering_branch];

                        foreach ($branchesToProcess as $branch) {
                            if (session('branch') !== $branch) {
                                session(['branch' => $branch]);
                            }
                            $this->processLedgerReport($currentLedger, $fromDate, $toDate, $branch);
                        }
                    }
                });

            // Logging the overall completion time
            $logFile = storage_path('logs/dailySummaryLogs/DailyReportsController_last_run.log');
            $logMessage = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString() . ' - Daily summary process completed from ' . $fromDate . ' to ' . $toDate . '--' . $presentCompany;
            file_put_contents($logFile, $logMessage . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

            $secondLogFile = storage_path('logs/dailySummaryLogs/DailyReportsController_saves.log');
            $secondLogMessage = '---------------End of' . Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString() . '---------------';
            file_put_contents($secondLogFile, $secondLogMessage . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Handle exception
            $logFile = storage_path('logs/dailySummaryLogs/DailyReportsController_error.log');
            $logMessage = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString() . ' - Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            file_put_contents($logFile, $logMessage . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }

    private function processLedgerReport($currentLedger, $fromDate, $toDate, $branch)
    {
        try {
            $this->ledgerReport->reportType = 'ledger';
            $this->ledgerReport->ledger = $currentLedger;
            $this->ledgerReport->fromDate = $fromDate;
            $this->ledgerReport->toDate = $toDate;

            $ledgerEntries = $this->ledgerReport->getLedgerEntries();

            if (empty($ledgerEntries['ledger_entries'])) {
                return;
            }

            $ledgerEntriesCollection = collect($ledgerEntries['ledger_entries']);
            $groupedData = $ledgerEntriesCollection->groupBy('date');
            $result = [];
            $finalTotal = 0;

            foreach ($groupedData as $date => $items) {
                $totalDebit = $items->sum('debit');
                $totalCredit = $items->sum('credit');

                $result[$date] = [
                    'total_debit' => $totalDebit,
                    'total_credit' => $totalCredit,
                    'total' => $totalDebit - $totalCredit,
                ];
                $finalTotal += $result[$date]['total'];
            }

            foreach ($result as $date => $summary) {
                $parsedDate = Carbon::parse($date)->format('Y-m-d');
                DailySummary::updateOrCreate(
                    [
                        'date' => $parsedDate,
                        'ledger_id' => $currentLedger->ledger_id,
                        'company_id' => session('company'),
                        'branch_id' => $branch,
                    ],
                    [
                        'ledger_name' => $currentLedger->ledger_name,
                        'total_debit' => $summary['total_debit'],
                        'total_credit' => $summary['total_credit'],
                        'grand_total' => $summary['total'],
                        'grand_total_type' => ($summary['total'] > 0) ? 'Debit' : 'Credit',
                    ]
                );
                // Logging details for each successful save
                $logFile = storage_path('logs/dailySummaryLogs/DailyReportsController_saves.log');
                $logMessage = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString() . ' - Ledger ID: ' . $currentLedger->ledger_id .
                    ', Date: ' . $parsedDate . ', Branch: ' . $branch;
                file_put_contents($logFile, $logMessage . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Error in Daily Summary processLedgerReport', [
                'message' => $e->getMessage(),
                'stack' => $e->getTraceAsString(),
            ]);
        }
    }
}


I call this job using the nssm scheduler and a custom-made command.
I needed to change the session, so I considered using cache to store the session branch. Is this a good idea, and do you have any suggestions?
Thank you.
